# How can I link a local pdf file on html file - the html file is showing on UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am showing a local html file on my UiWebView using following code.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test.html"];  

NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];    

NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:bundlePath];

[_webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
[_webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

App is showing the html correctly. In the test.html there is a link to local pdf file hello.pdf. This pdf is added to the project. But when I click on the link nothing happens. I want to load pdf on my web view when user clicks on the link.

I want to use the UIWebView delegate to send requests for internet hyperlinks (e.g. http://www.google.com) to the safari app.

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType 
{
    NSLog(@"%@",inRequest.URL.absoluteString);
    if([inRequest.URL.absoluteString rangeOfString:@"hello.pdf"].location == NSNotFound)
    {
        if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) 
        {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
            return NO;
        }
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
       return NO; 
    }
}
```

Comment: what does the link look like? is it simply href='document.pdf'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have stated more clearly that you wanted internet hyperlinks to load in Safari and local hyperlinks to load in your `UIWebView`.

I've just tested this and it does what you want:

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType 
{
    if (inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
        if ([inRequest.URL.absoluteString rangeOfString:@"http://"].location == NSNotFound) {
            return YES;
        }
        else {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
            return NO;
        }
    }
    else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

This works by only loading links in your `UIWebView` that don't contain the hyper text type protocol prefix (http://).

*Tip:* Make sure you've set the delegate for the `UIWebView` in the `viewDidLoad` method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    webView.delegate = self;
}
```

Comment: I dont know how I can provide more explanation on my question. But you are right about one thing I should not have returned NO on my else. On that basis I am accepting you answer

Comment: I applied an edit to your original question. You didn't make it 100% clear that you wanted hyperlinks to open in the safari application. "I want to load pdf on my web view when user clicks on the link. BTW I am using UIWebView delegate to send user to website when they click on link like (http://www.google.com)" <- sending a user to a website doesn't mean the same thing as opening safari! You are forgiven though :)